# Convergence of a series with M-test

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

> $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\exp({x^k})}{5k^2}$

I have a request on the convergence of this function series over the interval $(0,1)$, (look above). My idea is to do the $M$-test or comparison criterion. So because of that you can say that $e^{x^k}$ is $< e^x$ and then do the Quiotient criterion. Is that one good approach?

Comment: $e^{x^{k}}<e^{1}$.

Comment: Okay, and then we have e/(5k^2) and then with we have e/5 * 1/k^2 and that is convergent

Comment: It is better to use some latex to write math formula and use dollar signs to include the code. Ref: https://latexeditor.lagrida.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$e^y$ is monotonically increasing, so $e^y<e^1$ for every $y\in (0, 1) $. In particular if $x\in(0, 1) \implies x^k\in (0, 1) $ for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$. So we have that $$\frac{e^{x^k}}{k^2}<\frac{e^1}{k^2}\sim \frac{1}{k^2}, $$ and by the M-test $$\sum \frac{e^{x^k}}{k^2}, $$ converges uniformly in $(0, 1) $.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. It is possible to show that the series is continuous?

Comment: The partial sums are continuos functions, so the uniform limit of a continuos Sequence is continuous

Comment: So if the question is: the boundary function is continuous than I must build the limits

Comment: What do you mean by boundary function?

Comment: if you want to check if the limit function is continuous because we should also show that the limit function is continuous

Comment: You dont have to. The sums $f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{e^{x^k}}{k^2}$ are continuous, if $f$ is the uniform limit of the $f_n$ we Know that is continuous, is a theorem